# Dois campos com filtro no segundo - Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Ola Família stackOverflow

Estou finalizando um projeto e estou com problemas no datepicker.
Tenho dois campos datepicker (calendario e calendario1), funcionando perfeitamente, entretando preciso que o campo "calendario1" apresente datas a partir da escolha da data do campo "calendario". Será que consegui me fazer entender?

Resumindo: o campo calendario é escolhido 14-01-2018 e as opções de data no calendario1 deve ser a partir de 15-01-2018

Segue os codigos datepicker

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#calendario" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: false,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        maxDate: '-1d +12m',
        minDate: '+1d',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
    });
    $( "#calendario1" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: false,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        maxDate: '-2d +12m',
        minDate: '+3d',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Poderia montar um exemplo no http://jsfiddle.net? Assim é mais fácil de lhe ajudar

Comment: E aí Rodrigo! Resolveu a questão?

Answer (score -1):

Para definir uma data inicial no **[jQuery Datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)** usa-se a opção **[minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)** no formato:

```
minDate: new Date(ano, mês, dia)
```

E para alterar a propriedade de um `input` com Datepicker, você usa:

```
$(seletor).datepicker("option", {propriedade: novo_valor} );
```

Para detectar uma alteração em uma data, você usa o método `onSelect`:

```
onSelect: function(){
   executar algum código
}
```

Então, para alterar a data inicial do segundo `input #calendario1`, usamos o `onSelect` no primeiro `input` passando a data selecionada na função e pegando os valores (dia, mês e ano):

```
onSelect: function(dia){
   var dia = dia.split("-").map(Number),
       d = dia.pop()+1,
       m = dia[1]-1,
       a = dia.shift();
   $("#calendario1").datepicker("option", {minDate: new Date(a, m, d)} );
}
```

**Edit:** acrescentei um `.val('')` para esvaziar e redefinir o segundo `input`.

**Exemplo (vide comentários no código):**

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#calendario" ).datepicker({
      onSelect: function(dia){ // o parâmetro "dia" é a data selecionada
         var dia = dia.split("-").map(Number), // quebro a data em array com números inteiros
             d = dia.pop()+1, // pego o dia seguinte ao selecionado
             m = dia[1]-1, // pego o mês selecionado -1 (é preciso subtrair por 1 porque o retorno é um mês a frente)
             a = dia.shift(); // pego o ano selecionado
         $("#calendario1").val('').datepicker("option", {minDate: new Date(a, m, d)} );
      },
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: false,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        maxDate: '-1d +12m',
        minDate: '+1d',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
    });
    $( "#calendario1" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: false,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        maxDate: '-2d +12m',
        minDate: '+3d',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="calendario" >
<input type="text" id="calendario1" >
```

Comment: Eu seleciono a data no calendario e no calendario1 também. Até ai OK. Mas se volto a selecionar outra data no calendario vejo que no calendario1 não começa a partir da nova data escolhida. Tem como atualizar a data no calendario1 caso selecione nova data no calendario?

Comment: rápido que meu dedo está coçando para um down kkkkk

Comment: Agora sim, eficaz e eficiente!! +1

Comment: Cansei um pouco

Comment: Entendo... às vezes enjoa mesmo.